# Is it bad to return value other than function in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Here is my code snippet:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { someMethod } from 'components/actions';

const MyComponent = {
   ...
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
   useEffect(() => dispatch(someMethod), [dispatch]);
   // Instead of: useEffect(() => { dispatch(someMethod); }, [dispatch]);
   ...
}
```

(1) I know dispatch will not return a function (but not sure what actually it return, a promise?), thus the input of `useEffect` will not return a function, thus no cleanup will occur/execute theoretically

(2) I know if input of useEffect returns a function, it will be used for cleanup, as React doc said.

(3) I do the above way, just for saving braces.

My question is, did I do anything wrong? Does input of useEffect can return something beside function, and will useEffect `ignore` it if it's not a function (not executable)?

BTW, I tested my code, but didn't find any bug occur, my question might be only related to `Best Practice`, and I checked docs, and also tried to view React source code, but failed to find any valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have anything to cleanup - you do not return function, and it is OK, and yeah, `useEffect` doesn't care, will or will not you return a function.
`Dispatch` returns object, and it will be ignored by `useEffect`.
But it can be more tricky actually, dispatch return value might change! - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/754
It depends on middleware you use, and each middleware can do your return object unpredictable, and some middleware might just return a function and it then will be executed by `useEffect` on unmount - and who knows what will happen - again, depends on middleware and it's inner logic.

So i would recommend to use brackets to be safe. Though only for this particular case, when you use `dispatch`